# remove duplicate characters immediately following one another

Tags: go

I am trying to remove duplicate characters that are immediately following each other.

E.g. "Whyyyy sooo ssserioooouuussss" should translate to "Why so serious"

In PHP PCRE this is possible like this

```
$text = preg_replace("/(.)\\1+/", "$1", $text);
```

I tried to do following

```
var duplicateRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`(?P<char>.)${char}+`)
text = duplicateRegex.ReplaceAllString(text, `${char}`)
```

[Test on play.golang.com](https://play.golang.org/p/aXoYCFLdr4O)

but it does not seems to work in go. Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: AFAIK, there are no back references in Go regexes so `${char}`, `\k<char>`, ... won't work in the pattern itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code. It ranges over the string rune by rune. If the rune is different from the last or it's the first rune, then add the rune to the result.

```
func removeDups(s string) string {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    var last rune
    for i, r := range s {
        if r != last || i == 0 {
            buf.WriteRune(r)
            last = r
        }
    }
    return buf.String()
}
```

In Go 1.10, the [bytes.Buffer](http://godoc.org/bytes#Buffer) can be replaced with [strings.Builder](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder) to minimize allocations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str := "Whyyyy sooo ssserioooouuussss 日本語語語"
fmt.Println(str)
var buf bytes.Buffer
var pc rune
for i, c := range str {
    if i ==  0{
        pc = c
        buf.WriteRune(c)
    }

    if pc == c {
        continue
    }

    pc = c
    buf.WriteRune(c)
}
fmt.Println(buf.String())
```

Result:

```
Whyyyy sooo ssserioooouuussss 日本語語語
Why so serious 日本語
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str := "Whyyyy sooo ssserioooouuussss"

var last rune

var sb strings.Builder

for _, r := range str {
    if r != last {
        sb.WriteRune(r)
        last = r
    } else {
        continue
    }
}

fmt.Println(sb.String())
```

Comment: This may or may not be correct, however, in any case, you should add a few lines of text to explain what you are doing and why you believe it to be the correct answer.